# How to get the line number of a match with scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

Using the following example:

```
$ scrapy shell http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/_static/selectors-sample1.html
```

where `selectors-sample1-html` is:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <base href='http://example.com/' />
  <title>Example website</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='images'>
   <a href='image1.html'>Name: My image 1 <br /><img src='image1_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image2.html'>Name: My image 2 <br /><img src='image2_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image3.html'>Name: My image 3 <br /><img src='image3_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image4.html'>Name: My image 4 <br /><img src='image4_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image5.html'>Name: My image 5 <br /><img src='image5_thumb.jpg' /></a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to get the line number of a match using Scrapy 1.1.2? For instance, something like:

```
$ response.selector.xpath('//title/text()').some_magic_to_get_line_number
$ # should output 4
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to get source line for text nodes, but for element nodes, you can hack into the underlying lxml object of the selector (with `.root`), and access `.sourceline` attribute:

```
$ scrapy shell http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/_static/selectors-sample1.html
2016-09-08 18:13:12 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-09-08 18:13:12 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-09-08 18:13:13 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/_static/selectors-sample1.html> (referer: None)
>>> response.selector.xpath('//title/text()')
[<Selector xpath='//title/text()' data=u'Example website'>]
>>> s = response.selector.xpath('//title/text()')[0]
>>> type(s)
<class 'scrapy.selector.unified.Selector'>
>>> type(s.root)
<type 'str'>
>>> s = response.selector.xpath('//title')[0]
>>> s.root
<Element title at 0x7fa95d3f1908>
>>> type(s.root)
<type 'lxml.etree._Element'>
>>> dir(s.root)
['__class__', '__contains__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_init', 'addnext', 'addprevious', 'append', 'attrib', 'base', 'clear', 'cssselect', 'extend', 'find', 'findall', 'findtext', 'get', 'getchildren', 'getiterator', 'getnext', 'getparent', 'getprevious', 'getroottree', 'index', 'insert', 'items', 'iter', 'iterancestors', 'iterchildren', 'iterdescendants', 'iterfind', 'itersiblings', 'itertext', 'keys', 'makeelement', 'nsmap', 'prefix', 'remove', 'replace', 'set', 'sourceline', 'tag', 'tail', 'text', 'values', 'xpath']

>>> s.root.sourceline
4
>>>
```